Artifacts on CosmosOS Canvas
I trying to create Canvas in CosmosOS, and when I start a function with Canvas, I get this:

I use this code in the function:
if (input == "lgui")
{
    canvas = FullScreenCanvas.GetFullScreenCanvas();
    try
    {
       

        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
        canvas.DrawPoint(pen, 69, 69);


        pen.Color = Color.GreenYellow;
        canvas.DrawLine(pen, 250, 100, 400, 100);


        pen.Color = Color.IndianRed;
        canvas.DrawLine(pen, 350, 150, 350, 250);


        pen.Color = Color.MintCream;
        canvas.DrawLine(pen, 250, 150, 400, 250);


        pen.Color = Color.PaleVioletRed;
        canvas.DrawRectangle(pen, 350, 350, 80, 60);

        Console.ReadKey();


        canvas.Mode = new Mode(800, 600, ColorDepth.ColorDepth32);


        pen.Color = Color.LimeGreen;
        canvas.DrawRectangle(pen, 450, 450, 80, 60);

        Console.ReadKey();

        Stop();
    }

How to fix it?
I trying to make a graphics driver, but the example code has many errors.
Update: On the VmWare I have blank screen, on Virtualbox artifacts, on the LBochs(Bochs based emulator for android) the image is normal :\
